# $A\subset\Bbb R^n\text{ open}, p\in\Bbb R^n-A$. Then $A\cup\{p\}$ is open $\iff$ $p$ is isolated on $\partial A$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $A\subset\Bbb R^n$ open and $p\in\Bbb R^n-A$, where $n>1$. Then $A\cup\{p\}$ is open if, and only if, $p$ is isolated on $\partial A$.

Tried a few things but none of them worked as expected, could you give a clue to tackle this problem ?

***Edit (after a long time):***

Initially  my expectations were that $A$ looks like $\Bbb R^n$ minus countable points. But same ideia looks to be true if we omit countable points from a open set. Let me explain my new idea:

I was thinking if some reformulation of this problem would help. Then I found this one: Let $X\subset\Bbb R^n$, where $n>1$, be any set and take a point $x\in X$. Then, $x$ is an interior point of $X$ if, and only if, $x$ is isolated on the boundary of $X-\{x\}$. And this is essentially the fact that the interior of a set is disjointed from it's boundary.

Am I right ?

Comment: You're missing something in the question. William Elliot's counterexample still holds if you replace $A$ by the open ball center (1/2,0,...), radius 1/2.

Comment: Where did you get this problem? I think I've seen it somewhere but can't remember where. Maybe in Dugundji or Munkres.

Comment: @Zero It's from Elon Lages's Analysis book

Answer (score 1):

**Counter example:**
Let $n = 1, A = (0,1)$ and $p = 1$.  The boundary of $A$ is just $\{0,1\}$ and $p$ is an isolated point of $\{0,1\}$. Although, $A\cup\{p\}=(0,1]$ is not open.

Comment: Sorry William, I've forgot the $n>1$ condition. Thank you for remembering that information. See my edit.